# Why use an exception instead of if...else

Tags: exception

For example, in the case of "The array index out of bound" exception, why don't we check the array length in advance:

```
 if(array.length < countNum)
 {
 //logic
 }
 else
 {
 //replace using exception
}
```

My question is, why choose to use an exception? and when to use an exception, instead of `if-else`

Thanks.

Comment: Exceptions are for *exceptional conditions* and should not be used for logic.

Comment: i believe user defined exceptions were created to use them for logic and flow control

Answer (score 3):

It depends on acceptable practices for a given language.

In Java, the convention is to always check conditions whenever possible and not to use exceptions for flow control.  But, for example, in Python not only using exception in this manner is acceptable, but it is also a preferred practice.

Comment: +1 I'm not sure if it'd be "preferred" in Python in this example, but good for pointing out that the language used plays a factor in the "correct usage" of exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

They are used to inform the code that calls your code an exceptional condition occurred. Exceptions are more expensive than well formed if/else logic so you use them in exceptional circumstances such as reaching a condition in your code you cannot handle locally, or to support giving the caller of your code the choice of how to handle the error condition.

Usually if you find yourself throwing and catching exceptions in your own function or method, you can probably find a more efficient way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

There are many answers to that question.  As a single example, from Java, when you are using multiple threads, sometimes you need to interrupt a thread, and the thread will see this when an InterruptedException is thrown.

Other times, you will be using an API that throws certain exceptions.  You won't be able to avoid it.  If the API throws, for example, an IOException, then you can catch it, or let it bubble up.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example where it would actually be better to use an exception instead of a conditional.

Say you had a list of 10,000 strings. Now, you only want those items which are integers. Now, you know that a very small number of them won't be integers (in string form). So should you check to see if every string is an integer before trying to convert them? Or should you just try to convert them and throw and catch an exception if you get one that isn't an integer? The second way is more efficient, but if they were mostly non-integers then it would be more efficient to use an if-statement.

Most of the time, however, you should not use exceptions if you can replace them with a conditional.

Answer (score 1):

As someone has already said, 'Exceptions' in programming languages are for exceptional cases and not to set logical flow of your program. For example, in the case of given code snippet of your question, you have to see what the enclosing method's or function's intention is. Is checking `array.length < countNum` part of the business logic or not. If yes, then putting a pair of `if/else` there is the way to go. If that condition is not part of the business logic and the enclosing method's intention is something else, then write code for that something else and throw exception instead of going the `if/else` way. For example you develop an application for a school and in your application you have a method `GetClassTopperGrades` which is responsible for the business logic part which requires to return the highest marks of the student in a certain class. the method/function definition would be something like this:

```
int GetClassTopperGrades(string classID)
```

In this case the method's intention is to return the grades, for a valid class, which will always be a positive integer, according to the business logic of the application. Now if someone calls your method and passes a garbage string or `null`, what should it do? If should throw an exception e.g. `ArgumentException` or 'ArgumentNullException' because this was an **exceptional** case in this particular context. The method assumed that always a valid class ID will be passed and NULL or empty string is NOT a valid class ID (a deviation from the business logic).

Apart from that, in some conditions there is **no prior knowledge about the outcome of a given code** and **no defined way to prevent an exceptional situation**. For example, querying some remote database, if the network goes down, you don't have any other option there apart from throwing an exception. Would you check network connectivity before issuing every SQL query to the remote database?

Answer (score 0):

Using exceptions is universal method to notify other part of code that something wrong happened in a loosely coupled way. Let imagine that if you would like to handle some exceptional condition by using if.. and else.. you need to insert into different part of your code some arbitrary variables and other assertions which probably would easily led to have spaghetti code soon after.

Let next imagine that you are using any external library/package and it's author decided to put in his/her code other arbitrary way to handle wrong states - it would force you to adjust to its way of dealing with it - for example you would need to check if particular methods returns true or false or some other provided variables has proper values. Using exceptions makes handling errors much more easy - you just assume that if something goes wrong - the other code will throw exception, so you just wrap the code in try block.